# How to create a tablespace only for schema's LOBs in Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, schema, tablespace, lob

I have a schema **S** linked to a default tablespace **T1** in an Oracle database.

I want to create another tablespace **T2** only for LOBs linked to the same schema **S**.

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: You can do this, but are you sure you want to?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Usually it's better to put all objects in a schema in the same tablespace - there's no performance difference, and it's easier to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle you can specify the tablespace for each LOB column just like for each table. That means that you can create a different tablespace (or tablespaces) for your LOB data than your regular table data. Quite often this technique is used to store LOB data on cheaper storage than the table's data:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE DATATBS1 DATAFILE 'datatbs1.dbf';

CREATE TABLESPACE LOBTBS1 DATAFILE 'lobtbs1.dbf';

CREATE TABLE T1 (id NUMBER, text CLOB)
LOB (text) STORE AS SECUREFILE (TABLESPACE LOBTBS1)
TABLESPACE DATATBS1;

SELECT tablespace_name
 FROM user_lobs
  WHERE table_name = 'T1' AND column_name = 'TEXT';

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
LOBTBS1

SELECT tablespace_name
 FROM user_tables
  WHERE table_name = 'T1';

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
DATATBS1
```

For more information see [LOB Storage Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADLOB/adlob_tables.htm#CIHEBABG) in the Database SecureFiles and Large Objects Developer's Guide.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but for all existing and new tables you should manually write lob tablespace. The same behavior is for lob indexes. How to do that see link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_tables.htm#CIHEBABG